# C# Excel VSTO Addin provide code for VBA in Excel - Intellisense Support in VBA

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, intellisense, excel-addins

I am interested in creating a custom VSTO Excel Addin to provide customized classes for VBA in Excel. This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-calling-code-in-a-vsto-add-in-from-vba?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) provides a walkthrough for this task, however there is one question left for me: How to provide intellisense support for VBA for this customized routines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IntelliSense technology available in VBA is based on the COM technology. So, if you try using the late-binding technology with any Office application automated you will not find the IntelliSense for such objects as well. Only early-binding technology allows using this technology and get intellisense available to developers. You need to create a COM interface which could be implemented on both sides. After adding a COM reference to that library you may get hints like intellisense.

Out of the box VSTO doesn't provide anything for getting the IntelliSense available in VBA.

Comment: Ok, but if I create a COM interface, then I lose the "VSTO Click Once Feature" (publish to a network location, where users can install from and receive updates)

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct.